# Can I create a TemplateRef from a string?

Tags: angular

## The component I got

Let's say I have the following super simple component:

```js
class MyComponent {
    @Input()
    simpleContent: string;
    @ContentChild(TemplateRef)
    content: TemplateRef<any>;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <div *ngIf="simpleContent; else complexContent">{{simpleContent}}</div>
    <ng-template #complexContent>
        <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="content"></ng-container>
    </ng-template>
</div>
```

At the option of the user, it can be used like this:

```html
<my-component simpleContent="Hello world!"></my-component>
```

Or it can be used like this:

```html
<my-component>
    <ng-template>Hello world!</ng-template>
</my-component>
```

While the second option allows for embedded HTML and thus more complex formatting, the user can choose the simple approach with just an attribute for the majority of cases.

## Question

I would like to simplify the component and get rid of the if/else in the template. I imagine something like this:

```js
class MyComponent {
    @ContentChild(TemplateRef)
    content: TemplateRef<any>;
    @Input()
    set simpleContent(value: string) {
        this.content = new TemplateRef(value);
    }
}
```

```html
<div>
    <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="content"></ng-container>
</div>
```

Obviously this does not work, because `new TemplateRef(value)` is not possible.

**Is there a way to create a basic simple template dynamically at runtime?**

Comment: I think this approach: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fjcbn6?file=src%2Fapp%2Fsimple%2Fsimple.component.ts is more suitable to your use case.

Comment: I don't understand why you just don't use `ng-content`? So the client decide if use simple or complex content inside the component `<my-component>simple or complex</my-component>` because both contents will be inside the same `<div>` (layout)

Answer (score 4):

In these examples we're not actually "creating" the templateRef, since this would require angular renderer factories and a lot of extra code to create proper Injectors for the new EmbeddedView. And we just need to edit the template on the fly with a string value so here goes.

### Example 1: Using ng-container

Template markdown extending the OP's question using ng-container

```html
<div>
    <ng-container #container></ng-container>
</div>
<!-- Adding an empty template for later use -->
<ng-template #content><ng-content></ng-content></ng-template>
```

Then the component's code would look like this

```ts
export class Component implements AfterViewInit{

    @ViewChild("content") contentRef: TemplateRef<any>;
    @ViewChild("container", {read: ViewContainerRef}) containerRef: ViewContainerRef;

    divRef: HTMLElement;
    value: string = "";
    @Input()
    set simpleContent(value: string) {
        if(this.divRef){
           this.divRef.innerHTML = this.value;
        }
        this.value = value;
    }

    constructor() {}

    ngAfterViewInit(): void {
      let div = document.createElement("div");
      div.innerHTML = this.value;

      var embeddedViewRef = this.contentRef.createEmbeddedView(this.containerRef);
      this.containerRef.insert(embeddedViewRef);
      embeddedViewRef.rootNodes[0].replaceWith(div);
      this.divRef = div;
    }
}
```

In this example we are getting a reference to the ng-content tag located in the rootNodes of the EmbeddedView and replacing it with our native html template string.

### Example 2: Using elementRef

Since we're injecting with nativeElements in the first example, i thought why not directly edit the first div tag by getting it's reference with ViewChild and ElementRef.

```ts
@Component({
    selector: "component",
    template:`<div #ref></div>`
})
export class Component implements AfterViewInit{

    @ViewChild("ref", {read: ElementRef}) tref: ElementRef;
    
    value: string = "";
    @Input()
    set simpleContent(value: string) {
        if(this.tref) this.tref.nativeElement.innerHTML = this.value;
        this.value = value;
    }
    constructor() {}
    ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        this.tref.nativeElement.innerHTML = this.value;  
    }
}
```

### Example 3: Using simple Databinding

And finally since it's just a  simple string template we want to inject in the component why not simply use [databinding](https://angular.io/guide/binding-syntax#types-of-data-binding) on innerHTML

```ts
@Component({
    selector: "component",
    template:`<div [innerHTML]="value"></div>`
})
export class Component{
    value: string = "";
    @Input()
    set simpleContent(value: string) {
        this.value = value;
    }
    constructor() {}
    
}
```

---

After almost 2 years i doubt OP was still waiting for an answer. This reply was mainly a challenge for me but i learned a few things myself doing research. Like this article about [dom manipulation techniques in angular](https://indepth.dev/posts/1052/exploring-angular-dom-manipulation-techniques-using-viewcontainerref)

In hope this could be useful to someone out there