# How to send a template to a Dialog component in Angular

Tags: angular, templates, angular-material

I am trying to insert a template inside a MatDialog reusable component, that is open by a click event.

**1) parent component**

has the click event code that opens the MatDialog. Here, I try to send a template (which is another component directive) as a data property, to be used in the dialog component

```
openModal():void{
 this.dialog.open(DialogComponent, {
  data: {title:"My title",template:"<app-othercomp></app-othercomp>"}
 });  
}
```

**2) Reusable dialog template**
It has the ng-template as a placeholder where to insert the template

```
<div mat-dialog-content>
 <ng-template #templatePlaceholder></ng-template>
</div>
```

**3) Reusable dialog component**
It has the catch of the ng-template reference

```
@ViewChild('templatePlaceholder', { read: TemplateRef }) templatePlaceholder!: TemplateRef<any>;
```

and i inject the data in the constructor (and i can access to it) and then i tried to use ngOnInit to make something like this

```
this.templatePlaceholder = this.data.template;
```

But it does not work. I was able to make appear the string of the template as just text, but not render it.

I read a lot information on the web:[example 1]

but i am unable to solve this puzzle. Can anyone point me to the right document sample or help me out? Thank you.

**UPDATE ONE**
I tried add this in the parent component that opens the modal:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-othercomp',
  template: `<div>
    ddd
    <hr />
  </div>`,
})
export class AppMyContentComponent {}
```

and then...

```
openModal():void{
 this.dialog.open(DialogComponent, {
  data: {title:"My title",template:AppMyContentComponent}
 });  
}
```

and still no success... but your suggestions are helping me!

**UPDATE TWO**
I created this [working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-y7ittc?file=src/app/app.component.ts): in the app.component.ts in line 12 is where i need to define the html which is a directive for another component.

Comment: 2) => Rendering a template should be done with `<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="data.template; context: xxxxx"></ng-container>` instead of the `<ng-template ...>` gibberish

Comment: Thank you but i might by dumb but it does not work: `<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="data.template"></ng-container>` because data.template is the string `"<app-othercomp></app-othercomp>"`. It appears it is waiting for a TemplateRef. I read [this](https://www.tektutorialshub.com/angular/ng-template-in-angular/) and [this](https://angular.io/api/core/TemplateRef#description) but i am just making circles.

Comment: I also found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54967339/can-i-create-a-templateref-from-a-string) but it sends just html, not a string to be rendered by angular...

Comment: Why would you want to render an html string? Are you storing html in the database and want to render this inside a modal? That's risky, but can be accomplished using `bypassSecurityTrustedHtml` (would have to look it up...)

Comment: I've written a similar component (only better) on the [following demo page](https://bootstrap.mintplayer.com/overlays/modals) ([source code](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/tree/master/apps/ng-bootstrap-demo/src/app/pages/overlay/modal)). Hope you understand how it works. Ask away if you need something explained.

Comment: Pieterjan, I want to pass another component into the modal.

Comment: Pieterjan, i am obliged to use the dialog from angular material.... but your code is awesome!

Answer (score 2):

**Note**: Angular has a compiler, it means when you write templates in a component then templates becomes javascript instructions and there is no html markup anymore. so you cannot use dynamic template as `<app-othercomp></app-othercomp>` at runtime.

But if you want to pass an angular component as dynamic template you can use [`@angular/element`](https://angular.io/guide/elements) package to produce standard *web component* from it.

```
createCustomElement(AppOtherComponent)
```

and then use the template as `innerHTML` in dialog

```
<div mat-dialog-content [innerHTML]="data.template"></div>
```

Comment: I can't follow this path because i am not allowed to add more packages.... but your answer is very educative for angular's beginners like me.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to specify the content of the modal in html instead of ts

```
<ng-template #modalTemplate>
    <app-othercomp></app-othercomp>
</ng-template>
```

And use it in typescript:

```
@ViewChild('modalTemplate') modalTemplate!: TemplateRef<any>;

openModal():void{
  this.dialog.open(DialogComponent, {
    // data: {title:"My title",template:"<app-othercomp></app-othercomp>"}
    { data: { title: 'My title', template: this.modalTemplate } }
  });  
}
```

### Edit

[Here's a StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-75wtcu-qud78b?embed=1&file=src/app/dialog-overview-example.html) where the template is specified in the component calling the modal, as you state

Comment: this is more close but the component i want to insert is not already defined in the html of the modal. It is coming from the component that opens the modal...

Comment: I add more code in the question... thank you.

Comment: This IS it. You can simply specify this template anywhere you like (as long as it's a HTML file) and pass it in whereever you call the material `Dialog` service. The HTML I posted is specified in the same component that opens the modal. It's not an actual component instance, but a template. The angular `Dialog` service renders the template (probably using `<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet=...>`

Comment: Thank you for StackBlitz! That example i can understand but i guess i am not able to explain myself well. I do not want the ng-template to contain already the html code! I want to change it programmatically. This my difficult!  Please check my new working sample code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-y7ittc?file=src/app/app.component.ts. Thank you